# Use PHP to count the occurrences of a value per column in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two checkboxes in a form being sent to a MySQL database. If the checkbox is checked during form submit, the value in the database table is set to YES or left as null if not checked. So for example, the table structure after two entries looks like:

```
--------------------------------
ID | checkboxOne | checkboxTwo |
--------------------------------
1       YES            YES
2       YES            null
```

Using PHP, how could I count how many times *YES* occurs per column and echo the value? I think I have to use `array_count_values` but I can't figure out how to add that to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

The checkboxOne column value should be `2`, and the checkboxTwo value should be `1`.

Comment: Hey ! Maybe you should arrange your db in order to make it look like a real db by repeating on each line the check boxes number ? It will be easier to use array_count_value then. Just a thought ... Hope it brings value

Comment: Share the current output of $result so it will be easier to help !

Comment: Why would you use PHP to do this? You should normalize your DB and use SQL to count the values.

Comment: @Dharman because I am retrieving the values and displaying them in a HTML table. Is there a better way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: Use SQL window functions? Execute a separate SQL query to get totals?

Comment: Thanks @Dharman I have done some research into the SQL window functions and it already helps a lot.

Comment: Why don't you simply use count() function in MySQL?